# Regex without special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex for validate password

this is my regex configuration

```
@"^(?!.*[\s])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,32}$"
```

My criteria is

- The password must contain at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and a number;
- It cannot have any special character, accent or space;
- In addition, the password can be 6 to 32 characters long.

Tests I was waiting for:

- BIT123456 Is Invalid
- Year2021 Is Valid
- `Fing!2020 Is Invalid ( but it returns valid )`

My code to check for errors:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

      var totalTestCases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      string S = "";
      string pattern = @"^(?!.*[\s])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,32}$";

      var n = 0;
      do
      {
         n++;
         S = Console.ReadLine();
         if (S != "")
         {
            // Console.WriteLine("{0}", Regex.IsMatch(S, pattern) ? "Senha valida." : "Senha invalida.");
            string test = Regex.IsMatch(S, pattern) ? "Password valid." : "Password invalid.";
            Console.WriteLine(test);
         }
      } while (n < totalTestCases);
   }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are developing for an existing system, I would say that disallowing special characters in passwords is unwise from a security perspective.

Comment: It is not for a system, but for studying how a validation would work @John

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this Regex in your code it will work for your conditions.

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,32}$/
```

Replace pattern variable with below code :)

```
string pattern = @"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,32}$";
```

Comment: Why does it work? What did you change, why did you change it? Any or all of these things will make this a better answer

Comment: yes it is working, I just Remove Special character Regex.\  @00110001

Answer (score 1):

@Arpit Patel's answer is perfectly fine, but I'll just take a minute to explain what's wrong with your approach. Let's break it up:

- ^(?!.*[\s]): Negative look ahead says "No whitespace". That's fine.
- (?=.*[0-9]): Positive look ahead says: "There must be a number". That's fine.
- (?=.*[a-z]): Positive look ahead says: "There must be a lowercase letter". That's fine.
- (?=.*[A-Z]): Positive look ahead says: "There must be an uppercase letter". That's fine.
- .: Anything goes! That's obviously wrong.
- {6,32}: Length requirement.

So Arpit's answer:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,32}$
```

does away with the "anything goes" and inserts the legal characters instead. Thereby the negative look ahead is no longer needed since whitespace is prohibited.